# rviz: how to show video from cam in "Camera" but not "Image"

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and would like to visualize some results. I connected an usb camera and run rviz. But I can only see the video if I add "Image" display type. But if I add "Camera" display type, it shows nothing. How can I let it show in "Camera"?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240705/rviz:-how-to-show-video-from-cam-in-%22camera%22-but-not-%22image%22/) by [KWL](https://answers.ros.org/users/27640/kwl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The image displays just an image. The camera display will display the image with renderings of other data in the scene rendered on top of it, but in order to do that it requires `/tf` data that creates a tree between the "fixed frame" (set from the "global options" group in the "Displays" panel) and the frame that the image is in (this is determined by the value of the "header->frame_id" that is published within each image message).

So probably you don't have `/tf` data to show the image in the camera display. You can work around this by setting the fixed frame to be the same thing as the image's frame id.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KWL](https://answers.ros.org/users/27640/kwl/) on 2016-08-02**:
Thanks for your answer! I will try to work around this!

**Comment by [lotharchris](https://answers.ros.org/users/50557/lotharchris/) on 2020-01-11**:
This workaround worked for me, but when I add "Robot Model", it has an error unless I change the fixed frame to base_footprint, which breaks the camera image.
How do I create /tf data for the camera ?